# How to write post request query to a file in flask application?

Tags: python, flask

I want to save user's search terms to a file when they send a post request from a html form. The URL is below:

```
http://localhost:5000/np/wg
```

Then I have function definitions in np.py:

```
recent_searches = []
f = open(os.path.join(abspath, 'searches.txt'), 'a+')
f.seek(0)
for line in f:
    recent_searches.append(line.strip())

@bp.route('/wg', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def wg():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        query = request.form['query']

        print('my query: {}'.format(query))
        error = None
        if not query:
            error = 'Query term can not be empty！'
        f.write(query.strip())
        if error is None:
            ...
            return render_template('np/wg.html', recent_searches=recent_searches, query=query)

        flash(error)

    return render_template('np/wg.html', recent_searches=recent_searches)
```

My purpose is to read content from searches.txt, display it on home page, then write new use queries to the same file. The reading from the file is working, but it doesn't write new queries to the file.

I suspect that it might be due to the fact that the file handler 'f' is not closed? Where should I close it? If I close it it can't handle user's continuous queries.

EDIT：

I just found out that it actually write to the file, but only when I shut down the http service. So how to fix this and let it write to the  file without shutting down the service.

Comment: f.flush() actually write it immediately. But where should I close the file handle in such an application?

Answer (score 0):

It may help that defining a function to update both `searches.txt` and `recent_searches`.

```
def update_searches(current_search):
    recent_searches.append(current_search)
    file = open('searches.txt', 'a+')
    file.write(current_search + '\n')   # I added \n but it is up to you
    file.close()
```

And replace `f.write(query)` with `update_searches(query)` in your code so that keep recent_searches updated. (I assumed `query` is always string. If not, it is supposed to be handled additionally.)